# How can I use regular expressions and javascript to split the following command into tokens:

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, quotes, double-quotes

```
filter -n ""function(file) { return file.owner == "john"; }""
```

should be parsed into the following array:

```
[ 'filter',
  '-n',
  'function(file) { return file.owner == "john"; }' ]
```

Comment: Not possible with regex alone. Write a parser.

Comment: How do I mount this painting using superglue? Is there a particular reason you want to use a regex, it's not he best tool for this job.

Comment: @Tomalak For a sufficiently special-cased "regular" expression... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure how you want to handle the double quotes. Do you want to also be able to handle strings with only a single double quote on each end, or are the quotes always doubled?

```
var string = 'filter -n ""function(file) { return file.owner == "john"; }""';
var regex  = /([^"\s]+)|""(.*?)""/g;
var match;
var result = [];

while (match = regex.exec(string)) {
    result.push(match[1] || match[2]);
}

alert(result);
```

Result:

```
filter,-n,function(file) { return file.owner == "john"; }
```

Comment: there will always be 2 double quotes surrounding the string. I guess, if I use 1 double quote around the string, I will need to escape the quotes inside the string

Comment: var regex  = /([^"\s]+)|""(.*?)""/g, match; // what does match mean here ?

Comment: @Shahriar:  He's just predefining `match` as a variable.  Got lazy and did it all on one line.